# Safe to delete Primary Partition on multi-boot Windows system?

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I have 3 partitions on 1 disk set up as follows:

Win 7: System, Active, Primary Partition
Win 8: Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Logical Drive
Win 10: Logical Drive

I want to delete Win 7 so I can just make it as a storage partition. Is it safe to do so, i.e. will I still be able to multiboot to Win 8 and Win 10?

Thanks!

PS. Added pic

[image: Diskmgmt]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Disk Management in Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc thanks, I added the screenshot!

Comment: Are you sure you are currently able to boot into those two partitions on an extended partition?

Comment: @Ramhound Yup, worked for me with no issues! I basically cloned my HDD to an SDD, then swap it and installed the SDD. And yes, it multiboots without a problem and lets me choose which OS I want to boot into. I was able to boot to all 3 without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are booting from the Windows 7 partition, which is the only primary
partition. Therefore you can't delete it, as Windows cannot be
started from a logical drive.

If you would like to reuse its disk-space, I suggest to boot to
Windows 7 and use Disk Management to reduce the size of the
partition as far as it will let you. Ensure that there is at least
1 GB of free space in the disk.

To add the resulting unallocated space to one of the following partitions,
install a partition editor and move the other partition(s) on top of the
unallocated space so it follows the partition.
Then boot into this partition and use its Disk Management to resize it up.

Note that partition work is dangerous in case of an error, so take
careful backups.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try that then. Quick follow-up question, what about converting one the logical drive with the "boot" info to primary? Will that work as well? Or is that useless since it doesn't have the "system" info?

Comment: Some third-party partition editors claim this ability, such as [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-guide/convert-logical-partition-to-primary.html), but I'm skeptical that this will allow to delete Win7.

Comment: After uninstalling programs, defrag, check disk, etc. I was able to shrink it to 15 gb! All still boots up to all 3, so this works and I now have an extra unallocated partition. Yeah, I won't even bother trying out the primary conversion. Thanks!!